# What is the beat git workflow for collaborating on a project with several people?

Tags: github, workflow

I have been looking into what is the best way to collaborate on a github project with several people while being able to maintain code quality and avoid pushing mistakes to the trunk. I have found numerous resources on how alot of people prefer to do it. From what I gather the preferred way is to create a new branch with each new piece of development or fix you are making, pull request, and then merge to trunk. I want to know what other options are that seem to work for people?

Answer (score 0):

See [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).